# How to sum two subqueries with WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT *,
COALESCE((
    SELECT SUM(sum_points)
    FROM (
        SELECT SUM(user_points.points) AS sum_points FROM user_points
        WHERE user_points.user_id = user.user_id
        UNION ALL
        SELECT SUM(used_points.points) AS sum_points FROM used_points
        WHERE used_points.user_id = user.user_id
    ) t
), 0) AS total_points_credit
FROM user
```

But i get this error:

```
#1054 - Unknown column 'user.user_id' in 'where clause'
```

How can i user the user.user_id value in WHERE condition in the subqueries?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your table names between `user_points`, `used_points` and `user`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
SELECT *,
       COALESCE((SELECT SUM(user_points.points) 
                 FROM user_points
                 WHERE user_points.user_id = user.user_id), 0)
        +
        COALESCE((SELECT SUM(used_points.points)  
                  FROM used_points
                  WHERE used_points.user_id = user.user_id), 0) AS total_points_credit
FROM user
```

Comment: Thank you...it worked fine. Sometimes we just have to think the simpler way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you need to have all of these subqueries. I feel like you can likely do what you're looking to do with:

```
SELECT A.user_id, SUM(B.points) + SUM(C.points) total_points_credit FROM user A
JOIN user_points B ON
    A.user_id = B.user_id
JOIN used_points C ON
    A.user_id = C.user_id

GROUP BY A.user_id
```

Comment: Thank you for answer...i'll try that way but for now the @Giorgos Betsos answer is working and is simpler.